# Как заменить с помощью sed удалить переход на новую строку в между тегами?

Tags: bash, sed

Например на входе:

```
module
 0008 
 0009 
 000A 
 000B 
 000C 
 000D 
 000E 
 000F 
  
module
 000C 
 000D 
 000E 
 000F
```

на выходе:

```
module 0008 0009 000A 000B 000C 000D 000E 000F
module 000C 000D 000E 000F
```

Пробовал вот так:

```
sed  -e "/module/,/^$/ {:a;N;$!ba; s/\n/ /}"
```

но результат такой:

```
module  0008 
 0009   000A 
 000B   000C 
 000D   000E 
 000F    
module  000C 
 000D   000E 
 000F
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Замените двойные кавычки на одинарные
2. Заменяйте `"\n "` на `" "`
3. Добавьте опцию `g`

Тогда ваш вариант будет работать.

К примеру, такой вариант:

```bash
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n / /g' input.txt
```

Даст такой результат:

```
module 0008  0009  000A  000B  000C  000D  000E  000F   
module 000C  000D  000E  000F
```

Похожий вопрос на английском: [How can I replace each newline (\n) with a space using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999)